# как получить количество элементов в map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Мне нужно вывести 1 название группы, что я сделал с помощью slice(0, 1), дальше нужно указать 'и еще {count} групп', пробовал через .length, не получилось.

```
<div>
    <Text style={{ fontSize: '12px' }}>{res.groups.slice(0, 1).map(res => res.name)} и еще {res.groups.map(res => res.length)}</Text>
</div>
```

```
{friend_first: 'Матвей', friend_second: 'Зубов', friend_photo: 'https://sun1.userapi.com/sun1-91/s/v1/ig2/DELkOiAx…?size=256x256&quality=95&crop=152,0,256,256&ava=1', percent: 38, groups: Array(5)}
```

Comment: А можно пример массива данных, с которым идёт работа?

Comment: @АлексейМельников, добавил

Comment: `res.groups.length - 1` так как первый вывели отдельно

Comment: `Array.prototype.map` по [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), которую почему-то некоторые не читает принимает функцию которой передает следующие аргументы `currentValue[, index[, array]]` — всего-то нужно взять третий аргумент и посмотреть его длину

Comment: @DaniilLoban, это не относится к вопросу

Comment: @Grundy в таком случае вопрос нуждается в доработке

Comment: @DaniilLoban, в теле вопроса указано что именно пытается сделать автор

Comment: Лично мне не понятно, какой ожидаемый результат. Форматирования кода не выполнено, ожидаемый результат не написан, собственная попытка решения приведена только на словах.
`res.groups.length - 1` если это и есть ответ, почему бы не оформить его и соответсвенно покончить с этим вопросом? –

Answer (score 0):

Для того, что бы вывести первый элемент из массива, использовать метод **slice()**, а затем **map()** лишнее. Достаточно просто вывести значение элемента по его индексу(Первый элемент имеет индекс 0).

Что бы узнать длину массива, надо обратиться к его свойству **length**

```
<div>
  {res.groups.length > 1 ?
    <Text style={{fontSize: '12px'}}>
      {res.groups[0].name} и еще {res.groups.length - 1}
    </Text> :
    <Text style={{fontSize: '12px'}}>
      {res.groups.length ? res.groups[0].name : 'Пусто'}
    </Text>
  }
</div>
```

Comment: в текущем подходе slice допустим если `0` и `1` - могут меняться

Comment: @Grundy В вопросе указан 1й элемент и по коду прослеживается то же самое. Если вдруг надо выводить X элемент из N'го массива, тогда это совершенно другая задача, да и вопрос должен звучать по другому, т.к. не понятно, что в данном случае будет "остаток". Если бы надо было вывести х первых элементов, то вопрос так же звучал бы по другому, как следствие и ответ был бы другим. Как я понимаю, обратившийся учится react и освоил вывод только через `.map()` вот и пытается использовать его всегда и везде, что и прослеживается по коду. Я показал как можно выводить по другому.